# Creating a View via SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
USE PayCalculator; 
CREATE VIEW PayCalculator.Pay 
AS
    SELECT
       PayStructure.WeekIncluded AS PaidWeeks, 
       PayStructure.PayDate AS PayDate, 
       dbo.PayStructure.PayYear AS PayYear, 
       Months.PMonth 
    FROM 
       PayStructure,Months
    INNER JOIN 
       Months.PMonth ON PayStructure.MonthID = PayCalculator.dbo.Months.PMonths
```

It seems the view with a join would not create. I'm baffled as to why, as it seems syntactically correct.

The error I get:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Pay, Line 5
>   Invalid object name 'Months.PMonth'.

But, all listed columns in side the database are correct

**dbo.Months**:

[image: Months Table]

**dbo.PayStructure**:

[image: PayStructure Tablee]

Even using:

```
USE PayCalculator;
GO

SELECT 
    PayStructure.WeeksIncluded, PayStructure.PayDate, PayStructure.PayYear
FROM 
    PayStructure AS sd
JOIN 
    AnualMonths.PMonths AS p ON sd.MonthID = AnualMonths.PMonths 
GO
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear.  There is no object/table/view called `Months.PMonth`.  I see you have a table called `DBO.Months` with a column called `PMonth`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is pretty messed up, you're using old join syntax (`FROM PayStructure, Months`) and also the normal join syntax (`JOIN ON...`) -- you're also trying to join straight onto a **column** and not onto the **table** (i.e., you're trying to `INNER JOIN Months.PMonth` instead of `INNER JOIN Months`

```
FROM PayStructure, Months
INNER JOIN Months.PMonth ON PayStructure.MonthID = PayCalculator.dbo.Months.PMonths
```

Based on what I think you're trying to do, try the script below:

```
USE PayCalculator; 
CREATE VIEW PayCalculator.Pay 
AS

SELECT ps.WeekIncluded as PaidWeeks,
       ps.PayDate as PayDate,
       ps.PayYear as PayYear,
       months.PMonth
FROM dbo.PayStructure ps
JOIN dbo.Months months on ps.MonthId = months.ID
```

Comment: New errors: *Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Pay, Line 9
Invalid column name 'PMonths'.*  AND *Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Pay, Line 4
The multi-part identifier "PayStructure.WeekIncluded" could not be bound.*

Comment: I think you're using the top script (which is simply copy-pasted from your question to explain the error) and not the bottom script.  Try the bottom script.

Comment: Using the bottom script, not the top

Comment: I don't even see anywhere in the bottom script the word `PMonths` with an **s**...  Not sure how you're getting an error which mentions PMonths using the bottom script

Comment: I also notice that your table doesn't have a column PayDate but your example script does... Other than that, the bottom script would work; here is a [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/33bd3/2) to prove it.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. I have seen where I have gone wrong, I thought i Created the Column when I actually didnt. So I gone ahead & Moved it into a new Table. Using this example with the MSDN Example for multiple joins. I sucessfully joined the three tables together in a view. Thank you for your help once again

Answer (score 1):

The data types of the joining columns should be the same:

```
CREATE VIEW PayCalculator.Pay 
AS

SELECT ps.WeekIncluded as PaidWeeks,
       ps.PayDate as PayDate,
       ps.PayYear as PayYear,
       months.PMonth
FROM dbo.PayStructure ps
JOIN dbo.Months months on ps.MonthId = months.ID
```